# Trying to Get the Earliest Date using MIN()

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, min

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS 'Transacton Date'
FROM AppProsHist
WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejection'
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
```

I thought this would allow for only the first (earliest) transaction date to be shown in my table, however, this still shows each transaction date. Is there a way to alter this so that I receive just one Date for the ID, AppID, Description?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE... ORDER BY... LIMIT 1`

Comment: No I need the other fields, but I want just one date to come up. So all that is above is correct, however I want only the first/earliest date to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to get the first record of the ordered set. `ASC` or `DESC` while ordering will set the direction in which to sort. So try

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS TransactionDate
FROM AppProsHist
WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejection'
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC, ID
```

Comment: Access gives me a Popup error saying "syntax error in ORDER BY clause" then highlights "LIMIT".  What do I do to fix this?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use spaces in aliases. So i updated my answer with the new alias `TransactionDate`

Comment: Oh, sorry sorry, there was a typo in my code, I updated it again

Comment: I think the issue I am having has to do with the "LIMIT" coming after "DESC". That's what the Syntax error keeps popping up for. Do you have any ideas how to fix the error?